# Why is ng-click only working with a function, not an assignment, in this directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to create a table based on an array of objects, sortable by clicking the headers. I have a question about this implementation of the sort feature.

```
let myDirectiveTemplate = `
<table class="directiveTable">
  <thead>
    <th ng-repeat="(key,val) in tableObjectArray[0] track by $index">
      <a href="" ng-click="changeCriteria(key)">
        {{key}}
      </a>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="object in tableObjectArray | orderBy:criteria track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="prop in object track by $index">
        {{prop}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`

let app2 = angular.module('myDirectiveModule', []);

let myDirective = () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      tableObjectArray: '=objects',
    },
    controller: myDirectiveController,
    template: myDirectiveTemplate,
  }
};

let myDirectiveController = ($scope) => {
$scope.changeCriteria = criteria => {
  $scope.criteria = criteria;
}
};

app2.directive('myDirective', myDirective);
app2.controller('myDirectiveController', myDirectiveController);
```

This works. However if in the template I change the ng-click to

```
ng-click="criteria = key"
```

it seems to do nothing. Even just displaying the variable with double curly braces, it does not change on click. I have used variable assignment in an ng-click before; what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for every item so you are changing  a primitive only within that child scope. Since there is no inheritance with primitives the parent scope in controller remains the same

If you were to use an object declared in controller, or use ControllerAs alias it would work fine due to inheritance

```
$scope.myModel ={criteria: 'defaultValue'}

ng-click="myModel.criteria = key"
<tr ng-repeat="object in tableObjectArray | orderBy:myModel.criteria track by $index">
```

From a debugging and testing stand point using a function is generally preferred

Comment: No matter how many times I heard "don't bind to a primitive" and, "you need a dot", I had to see it for myself. Thanks! I had actually tried dotting it but did NOT declare it in my controller first. D'oh!

Comment: Also helps to know where child scopes do get created internally. `ng-if` and `ng-include` are two others that catch people also

Comment: If you switch to using `ControllerAs` methodology problems like this will disappear because most everything has to have a dot then

Comment: Thanks, I just started studying the angular style guide, and that's one of the next changes I have to incorporate for sure.